# Find the expansion of $f (x) = x, 0 ≤ x ≤ \pi$ in a series of eigenfunctions of the Sturm–Liouville system $y''+\lambda y = 0, y (0) = 0, y (\pi)=0.$

Tags: fourier-series, orthogonality, sturm-liouville

I need to expand the given function in terms of eigen  functions series, firstly i find the solutions to the SLP and from there i get my eigen functions $n$ values, and then i find the coefficient Cn and simply multiply it with my eigen function to get the series! But  in this particular question, i dont know how to find the series if i have gotten more than one eigen function? 
P.S : I havent yet studied fourier series in depth,  just have studied orthogonal series and the definition to generalised fourier series.

Comment: I assume you mean $y''+\lambda y=0$.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant! i forgot to add the primes.

Comment: The eigenfunctions are $\sin(nx)$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$. These are mutually orthogonal with respect to $\langle f,g\rangle =\int_0^{\pi}f(t)g(t)dt$.

Answer (score 0):

The eigenfunctions are $\{ \sin(nx) \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, and the eigenfunction expansion is the Fourier sine series for $f$:
$$
     f \sim \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\int_0^\pi f(x')\sin(nx)dx'}{\int_0^\pi \sin^2(nx')dx'}\sin(nx)
$$
You can determine the normalization constants
$$
    \int_0^\pi \sin^2(nx')dx' = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^2(nx')dx \\
  = \frac{1}{4}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^2(nx')+\cos^2(nx')dx'=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
So
$$
   f\sim\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}x'\sin(nx')dx' \sin(nx).
$$
The remaining integrals are brute force.